# Call ruby script with other gems rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, call, conflicting-libraries

I'm trying to perform something like this:

`serialized = %x(ruby loader.rb)`

from a Controller but I have gem conflicts because loader.rb uses rubyXL (depends on rubyzip >= 1.1.6) and my Rails project uses `rubyzip -> 1.0.0. There are any way to handle this?

Comment: What about a `system` call?

Comment: Do you know `rails runner` or rake tasks ?

Comment: With system `system` Can I receive the returned data?

Comment: Rails runner uses the same context, I think that my gem conflict would persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you upgrade your Rails project to use rubyzip >= 1.1.6?

If you wanted to use the same version of rubyzip, you could do `%x(bundle exec ruby loader.rb)`. This will make sure that it uses the same version of rubyzip as your rails project.

Comment: That's my gem conflict, another gem uses 1.0.0. For that reason I'm trying to do it from an external script.

Comment: Which gem uses 1.0.0? Could you ask the gem maintainer to upgrade the dependency?